# My Android App crashes every time

Tags: android

Please help me, I'm kinda new with Android Programming. :(
This is the application that keeps crashing.
If i run this application by itself, it works perfect!
**TutorialThree.java**

---

```
package com.example.tutorialbasics;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TutorialThree extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView display;
    int toPhone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial3);
        toPhone= R.drawable.back_android1;

        display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVDisplay);
        ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVImage1);
        ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVImage2);
        ImageView img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVImage3);
        ImageView img4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVImage4);
        ImageView img5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVImage5);
        ImageView img6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVImage6);
        Button setWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSetWallpaper);

        img1.setOnClickListener(this);
        img2.setOnClickListener(this);
        img3.setOnClickListener(this);
        img4.setOnClickListener(this);
        img5.setOnClickListener(this);
        img6.setOnClickListener(this);
        setWall.setOnClickListener(this);


    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.IVImage1:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_android1);
            toPhone= R.drawable.back_android1;
            break;
        case R.id.IVImage2:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_android2);
            toPhone= R.drawable.back_android2;
            break;
        case R.id.IVImage3:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_android3);
            toPhone= R.drawable.back_android3;
            break;
        case R.id.IVImage4:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_android4);
            toPhone= R.drawable.back_android4;
            break;
        case R.id.IVImage5:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_android5);
            toPhone= R.drawable.back_android5;
            break;
        case R.id.IVImage6:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_android6);
            toPhone= R.drawable.back_android6;
            break;

        case R.id.bSetWallpaper:
            try{
                WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setResource(toPhone);
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        }
    }



}
```

**Tutorial3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVDisplay"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/back_android1" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSetWallpaper"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set Background" >
    </Button>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVImage1"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_android1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVImage2"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_android2" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVImage3"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_android3" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVImage4"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_android4" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVImage5"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_android5" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVImage6"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_android6" >
            </ImageView>




        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Once I call it via startActivity in my main application it crashes.
Main Application - **MyMenu.java**

---

```
package com.example.tutorialbasics;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyMenu extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // set up the button
        final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,
                R.raw.button_click1);

        final Intent i = new Intent(this, TutorialOne.class);
        final Intent i2 = new Intent(this, listV.class);
        final Intent i3 = new Intent(this, TutorialThree.class);

        // button1
        Button bTutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTutorial1);
        bTutorial1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(i);
                mpButtonClick1.start();
            }
        });

        // button2
        Button bTutorial2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTutorial2);
        bTutorial2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(i2);
                mpButtonClick1.start();
            }
        });

        // button3
        Button bTutorial3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTutorial3);
        bTutorial3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(i3);
                mpButtonClick1.start();
            }
        });

        // button4
        Button bTutorial4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTutorial4);
        bTutorial4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mpButtonClick1.start();
            }
        });

        // button5
        Button bTutorial5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTutorial5);
        bTutorial5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mpButtonClick1.start();
            }
        }); 

        // button6
        Button bTutorial6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTutorial6);
        bTutorial6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mpButtonClick1.start();
            }
        });

        // button7
        Button bTutorial7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTutorial7);
        bTutorial7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mpButtonClick1.start();
            }
        });

        // button8
        Button bTutorial8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTutorial8);
        bTutorial8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mpButtonClick1.start();
            }
        });

        // button9
        Button bTutorial9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTutorial9);
        bTutorial9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mpButtonClick1.start();
            }
        });     



    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater awesome = getMenuInflater();
        awesome.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuSweet:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, sweet.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        case R.id.menuToast:
            Toast display = Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            display.show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/orange" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200sp" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Radio Buttons"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/bTutorial1" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="List View"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/bTutorial2" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Wallpaper"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/bTutorial3" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Tutorial4"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/bTutorial4" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Tutorial5"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/bTutorial5" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Tutorial6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/bTutorial6" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Tutorial7"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/bTutorial7" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Tutorial8"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/bTutorial8" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Tutorial9"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/bTutorial9" >
    </Button>

    </LinearLayout> 
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="Copper"
        android:text="\nDada Acuin"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40sp"  
     ></TextView>  


</LinearLayout>
```

---

**Here is my Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tutorialbasics"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MyMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".sweet"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TutorialOne"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".listV"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".TutorialThree"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

**This is the error from the logcat**
Aneeq Anwar. I Tried to use the code youve give...but it still crashes..

here is my logcat

---

```
06-17 03:24:06.406: E/dalvikvm-heap(1051): Out of memory on a 9216016-byte allocation.
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tutorialbasics/com.example.tutorialbasics.TutorialThree}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.example.tutorialbasics.TutorialThree.onCreate(TutorialThree.java:24)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     ... 11 more
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     ... 26 more
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
06-17 03:24:06.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     ... 29 more
```

Comment: This is too many code, try to minimize it.

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: You are consuming too much memory, perhaps trying to load or manipulate an excessively large image.

Comment: yes, your right chris. i have large images in my drawable folder. so Ill just replace it with small quality image??

Comment: Thanks Chris Stratton! Its now working! I owe you one! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is error in your AndroidManifest.xml, change it to

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MyMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".sweet"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TutorialOne"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".listV"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".TutorialThree"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: thanks Nizam, ive done your advice, but still keeps crashing once I call it from my MyMenu.java :)
have any idea? hope you can help me

Comment: by the way the other activity is working fine...only tutorialthree.java is causing the crashes...

Answer (score 0):

Remove all intent filteres except one for your Launcher activity.

ie, There should be only one LAUNCHER activity.

Comment: While testing my app has up to six ones without problems.

Comment: Whats the Logcat says?

Comment: You noted that I did not ask the question? ;-)

Comment: oh.. You just edited it. :D  I did'nt noticed

Comment: i've edit the main article...you can see the errors their from the logcat...